# Faster way to do search and replace on a comma delimited line of text?

Tags: bash, perl, shell, csv

I have a CSV file in which I want to do a search and replace on each line to form SQL statements.  I have come up with this perl script ...

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -pi -e "s/(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)/REPLACE INTO student (ID, SIS_ID, STUDENT_NUM, USER_ID, OTHER_USER_ID) VALUES (REPLACE(uuid(), '-', ''), '\$24', '\$26', '\$2', '\$27');/g" $1
```

However, on a one line file, this takes about 15 seconds to run.  As you can imagine on a file of thousnads of lines, this takes hours.

Is there another way I can write the above that would speed up the search and replace?  I'm not married to Perl.  I'm using Mac 10.9.5, bash shell.

Comment: You're only using 4 of the 27+ fields you're capturing. Try replacing the capture groups you aren't using with `(?:.*)` instead (and adjusting the references to match). Also, use `[^,]` in place of `.` to limit the amount of backtracking the regex engine may be attempting.

Comment: Also, it's much faster to simply split the line into an array, then access the array elements you want.

Comment: Do you really want to do the substitution multiple times on the same line?

Comment: `awk -F, '{ printf "REPLACE INTO student ... %s, %s, %s, %s);", $24, $26, $2, $27 }'` would be a considerably more readable approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing each `(.*)` with this:
`([^,]+)`

I am sure it will reduce the execution time.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than search and replace, I'd probably [parse the CSV file](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) and construct the SQL statements line by line. It doesn't look like you're doing anything that needs the text-matching capabilities of a regular expression.

---

Edit: see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32213060/82262) on your other, very similar, potentially duplicate post for the "correct" way to do this.