# How do I apply this Perl expression to each line of the file?

Tags: bash, perl, shell

I'm using Mac 10.9.5, bash shell, and perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3). I have the following script ...

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -pi -e "s/([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^,]+?)/REPLACE INTO student (ID, SIS_ID, STUDENT_NUM, USER_ID, OTHER_USER_ID) VALUES (REPLACE(uuid(), '-', ''), '\$24', '\$26', '\$2', '\$27');/g" $1
```

However, when I run the script against a file ...

```
 sh myscript.sh ~/Downloads/myfile.csv
```

The above only gets run against the first line of the file and not against every line in the file, despite the fact the file has thousands of lines ...

```
davea$ wc -l ~/Downloads/myfile.csv
91552 /Users/davea/Downloads/myfile.csv
```

How do I adjust the above so that it applies the search and replace to every line of the file?

**Edit:** here is an example of a file that I'm passing in as input

```
 app.app.first_name,app.app.id,app.app.last_name,app.app.max_time,app.app.url,app.app.user_name,thirdparty.created,thirdparty.district,thirdparty.dob,thirdparty.ell_status,thirdparty.email,thirdparty.frl_status,thirdparty.gender,thirdparty.grade,thirdparty.hispanic_ethnicity,thirdparty.iep_status,thirdparty.last_modified,thirdparty.location.zip,thirdparty.name.first,thirdparty.name.last,thirdparty.name.middle,thirdparty.race,thirdparty.school,thirdparty.sis_id,thirdparty.state_id,thirdparty.student_number,thirdparty.id,matchmaker_result
 FirstName,0040FBA053464647BD51141EECF4437F,LastName,2014-09-15 20:46:11,cityunifiedca.springboardonline.org,mlastname,2014-04-04T23:03:29.916Z,51e76ab1d93412f47b000c32,6/12/2000,,,Paid,F,10,Y,Y,2015-08-19T21:33:13.989Z,90033-1803,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,A,Caucasian,51f811478a86244d2900033f,061200F010,6124939964,061200F010,533f3a412a1f1fea24c8e164,match
```

and here is the output of running the above

```
 REPLACE INTO student (ID, SIS_ID, STUDENT_NUM, USER_ID, OTHER_USER_ID) VALUES (REPLACE(uuid(), '-', ''), 'thirdparty.sis_id', 'thirdparty.student_number', 'app.app.id', 'thirdparty.id');atchmaker_result
 FirstName,0040FBA053464647BD51141EECF4437F,LastName,2014-09-15 20:46:11,cityunifiedca.springboardonline.org,mlastname,2014-04-04T23:03:29.916Z,51e76ab1d93412f47b000c32,6/12/2000,,,Paid,F,10,Y,Y,2015-08-19T21:33:13.989Z,90033-1803,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,A,Caucasian,51f811478a86244d2900033f,061200F010,6124939964,061200F010,533f3a412a1f1fea24c8e164,match
```

Comment: That command is already being run on every line. Also examples of what your input looks like would be useful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Faster way to do search and replace on a comma delimited line of text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210070/faster-way-to-do-search-and-replace-on-a-comma-delimited-line-of-text)

Comment: Hi, It is not running it on every line.  I included an example file and the output from running the script against that file.  This is not a duplicate of the cited question because the above deals with why isn't the script run on every line whereas the other question asks about a better way to write a search and replace statement.

Comment: It is running on every line, but the regex isn't matching because you have some empty fields in the second line. You should use `split` or Text::CSV instead of that godawful regex.

Comment: @DaveA I'm going to refer back to what I said in your other post (which _is_ a duplicate, because you're still trying to do the exact same thing), and that is: a regular expression is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Please try your regex and examples in a test tool like at regex101.com; though that one times out on your regex, maybe try one of the other online sandboxes mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the path to your input file as the first command line argument.

Note: array indices might be off because I simply took your regex match variables and shifted them down by one (i.e., I didn't test this code).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1 }) or die Text::CSV->error_diag;
open(my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0]) or die $!;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    print "REPLACE INTO student (ID, SIS_ID, STUDENT_NUM, USER_ID, OTHER_USER_ID) VALUES (REPLACE(uuid(), '-', ''), '$row->[23]', '$row->[25]', '$row->[1]', '$row->[26]');\n";
}

$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag;
close($fh);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets start by fixing your script to be a Perl script, one-liners are for the command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# example code from `man perlrun`

use warnings;
use strict;
my $extension = '.orig';
my $oldargv;
my $backup;
my $subre = "([^,]+?)";
my $bigre = "$subre," x 27 . $subre;
my $presub = "REPLACE INTO student (ID, SIS_ID, STUDENT_NUM, USER_ID, OTHER_USER_ID) VALUES (REPLACE(uuid(), '-', '')";
LINE: while (<>) {
if ($ARGV ne $oldargv) {
    if ($extension !~ /\*/) {
      $backup = $ARGV . $extension;
    } else {
      ($backup = $extension) =~ s/\*/$ARGV/g;
    }
    rename($ARGV, $backup);
    open(ARGVOUT, ">$ARGV");
    select(ARGVOUT);
    $oldargv = $ARGV;
}
  s/$bigre/$presub, '\$24', '\$26', '\$2', '\$27');/g;
} continue {
  print;    # this prints to original filename
}
select(STDOUT);
```

---

Then, looking at that regex, there's probably lines that contain `,,` for an empty field, so... you could fix the regex, but using one is kind of wrong here. Lets just change that one line from the above to this:

```
  my @f = split /,/;
  $_ = $presub . ", '${f[23]}', '${f[25]}', '${f[1]}', '${f[26]}');"
```

This assumes that there are no fields which, containing `,`, become quoted or escaped fields. For all that you'd use Text::CSV as Matt Jacob showed. I have similar caveats.

---

Alternatively you can stick with the regex if you must, but remove the `g` modifier, anchor the lines, and allow for empty captured groups.

```
s/^([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?)$/REPLACE INTO student (ID, SIS_ID, STUDENT_NUM, USER_ID, OTHER_USER_ID) VALUES (REPLACE(uuid(), '-', ''), '\$24', '\$26', '\$2', '\$27');/;
```

This doesn't timeout in [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) and works when given the flags `mg` for sample input, if you remove the `$` from the substitution's references to the captured fields.

Or modify the first script above changing these lines:

```
my $subre = "([^,]*?)";
my $bigre = '^' . "$subre," x 27 . $subre . '$';
...
s/$bigre/$presub, '\$24', '\$26', '\$2', '\$27');/;
```

Comment: Good job pointing out the actual reason for the non-matching behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your `s///` seems to be only matching the first line. Don't know why. However, that's a ridiculous regular expression. You want to split on commas into a list

```
perl -F, -lane '
    BEGIN { $t="REPLACE INTO student (ID, SIS_ID, STUDENT_NUM, USER_ID, OTHER_USER_ID) VALUES (REPLACE(uuid(), \047-\047, \047\047), \047%s\047, \047%s\047, \047%s\047, \047%s\047);\n"; }
    printf $t, $F[23], $F[25], $F[1], $F[26];
' file
```

```
REPLACE INTO student (ID, SIS_ID, STUDENT_NUM, USER_ID, OTHER_USER_ID) VALUES (REPLACE(uuid(), '-', ''), 'thirdparty.sis_id', 'thirdparty.student_number', 'app.app.id', 'thirdparty.id');
REPLACE INTO student (ID, SIS_ID, STUDENT_NUM, USER_ID, OTHER_USER_ID) VALUES (REPLACE(uuid(), '-', ''), '061200F010', '061200F010', '0040FBA053464647BD51141EECF4437F', '533f3a412a1f1fea24c8e164');
```

Comment: I have never used that -F argument. Seems useful.